# Referencing external files using django template

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I try to include external files for Javascript and CSS in the head tags in django template and they don't work. They work well when I put them before closing the body tag. Why? And another problem is that when I use inheritance, children don't see my external files. Can anybody help me please?

```
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{%static 'postare/style.css' %}"/>
    <link type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'postare/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel = "stylesheet"/>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'postare/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'postare/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'postare/scripts.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that this exact code works in <body> but not in <head>? What *exactly* happens when you put it in <body>? And what file is this code in - and where is that file in the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: yes.The script has a function which hides a class. When I asign that class to a div with the file in body it works, however, when I move the file in head it doesn't work.I tried assigning that class to a div in a child with the file in head and body and it does't work too.

Comment: The script file is called scripts.js and is located in app/static/app/scripts.js

Comment: What? Script files don't have <head> or <body>. *Where* is the code you have shown?

Comment: I have a html page with the code I have shown between the head tags. The code references several files, two css and three js which are located in another directory. In one of those files, in scripts.js to be more precise, I have a function which hides a class of a div tag, which is located between the body tags. But it doesn't hide the div, even though I have referenced it in the head tags. It works when I put <script ref.... just before i close the body tag

Comment: There's still too much unknown here. Is the script actually being loaded (ie can you see it in the browser dev tools)? And how does the script work - is it wrapped in `$(document).ready` so that it only runs when the doc is loaded?

Comment: it simply says on a row : $(".class").hide(); and i asigne the class to a div.No wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded static before `<html>` tag. And I used `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`
And it worked for me without of any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Django templates, or external files.

HTML pages are not magic; browsers simply interpret them in order. If a script is included at the top of a document, it can't immediately act on elements in the DOM, because the DOM is not yet loaded. That is why jQuery includes a method for delaying execution until the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ... code here ... 
});
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

Move this line to the top of template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

before `<html>` and `<head>` tags.

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn't work, tried it. It hides my div if I say in CSS: "visibility:hidden;" but if I try to add the same css property with JQuery it doesn't work.